# Redirect index.html

Tags: redirect, struts2

I have a Struts 2 app. We are getting many users going to index.html URLs.  I would like to redirect them.  My thinking is to just drop the 'index.html' from the URL and redirect to that directory (ie example.com/some/dir/index.html => example.com/some/dir/).

I am guessing there is a simple way of doing this in the struts.xml.

Comment: What is the purpose of doing that? I'm not sure of what you want but you can create an action called index.html and from there you can use forward, chain whatever but it will not change the URL.  If you want to do this on a consistent basis then URL rewriting might be a better solution, on linux I'd use iptables, on apache mod-rewrite... there are a lot of options for that just google url rewriting and decide if that is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but it sounds like you want a solution for a default action perhaps? Or a welcome file setting?

```
<package name="restful"  extends="struts-default">

    <!--  YOUR ACTIONS HERE  -->

    <default-action-ref name="default" />
        <action name="default">
            <result type="redirectAction">home</result>
    </action>

</package>
```

or

```
<package name="restful"  extends="struts-default">

    <!--  YOUR ACTIONS HERE  -->

    <default-action-ref name="default" />
        <action name="default">
            <result type="redirect">index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

or in your web.xml I've been able set an action as the welcome file:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```